# ElasticSearch analyzer auto-complete feature for alphanumeric

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have alphanumeric codes like Hcc18, HCC23, I23, which I want to store in **ElasticSearch**. Over this I want to build following two features:-

1. User can search complete alphanumeric code or just the integer part.
   **Example**:
   for hcc15 or 15, ***hcc15*** should be in the output and on the top of the results.
2. **Autocomplete feature**: When the user type let's say I42 the results should contain I420, I421 and so on.

My Elasticsearch current mapping is:

```
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "autoanalyer"
    }
  }
},
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "autoanalyer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
        ]
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "autotoken": {
        "type": "simple_pattern",
        "pattern": "[0-9]+"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query being made:

```
{
    "min_score": 0.1,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{ "match": {"code": search_term}}]
        }
    }
}
```

Two problems, I am facing with this approach is:-

1. Let's say I search for *I420*, now because mapping is based only on digits,
   I am getting all the codes related to number 420, but the exact
   match *I420* isn't coming on the top.
2. Will this mapping how will I be able to achieve the above mentioned
   **Autocomplete feature**.

Comment: Great question, it would have been better if you could have divided into 2 parts, so there are multiple requirements, I have just done, composing my answer and tested it with your data, please have a look and feel free to comment if you need more info.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I agreed that I should have break  it into two subparts. Also your answer solves most part of the problem.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja however it doesn't solve one of my problem. Let's say I have stored codes like E1151, E1152. When  I query for `E115` then  I am getting results like E1151, E1151, E1153, which is exactly and what I want. But then I search for 115 instead of E115 no result is coming. So for me it doesn't matter if the user types E115 or just 115. The autocomplete feature should work on numbers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had multiple requirements and all these can be achieved using

1. Creating a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) that tokenizes data according to our requirements.
2. Using a bool query with the combination of [the prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) (for autocomplete) and match for number search.

Below is the step by step example, using the OP data and queries.

### Index Def

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "autotoken" -->used your analyzer to extract numbers
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "autotoken": {
                    "type": "simple_pattern",
                    "pattern": "[0-9]+",
                    "preserve_original": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "code": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                    "number": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index few docs

```
{
  "code" : "hcc420"
}

{
  "code" : "HCC23"
}

{
  "code" : "I23"
}

{
  "code" : "I420"
}

{
  "code" : "I421"
}

{
  "code" : "hcc420"
}
```

### Search query (issue 1, searching for `I420`, should bring 2 docs in sample data `I420` and `hcc420` but `I420` must have more score as exact match)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "code": {
                            "value": "I420"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "code.number": "I420"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 2.0296195, --> note exact match having high score
        "_source": {
          "code": "I420"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "code": "hcc420"
        }
      }
    ]
```

### Part 2: The same search query can be used autocomplete feature

So searching for `I42` must bring `I420` and `I421` from sample docs

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "code": {
                            "value": "I42"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "code.number": "I42"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "code": "I420"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "code": "I421"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Let's take another example for number search, searching for `420` must bring `hcc420` and `I420`

### Search query

```
 {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "prefix": {
                            "code": {
                                "value": "420"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "code.number": "420"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }

And whoa, again it gave expected results 

Result
------


 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "code": "I420"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_number",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "code": "hcc420"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Opster that worked really well. Few things were not working like
when I quried for `I42` . then codes like I420, I421 were not coming on the top. I booted the prefix query by 10 i.e ` {"prefix": {"code": {"value": search_term, "boost": 10}}}`. And it worked. thanks again!

Comment: Sure, will do. Can you help with the issues I mentioned in the above comment?

Comment: @Abhimanyu, thanks for marking answer, waiting for your new question with detailed info :)